# Angular and Firebase - query with orderByKey correctly

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here I have a query, that works well:
`url` is a `$key` generated by Firebase when Article gets created.

```
   findArticlesByUrl(url:any) {
        return this.afDb.list('articles', {
          query: {
            orderByKey: url,
            equalTo: url
          }              
        }).do(console.log);
```

What I am curious about is that I need to tell it twice to query list by the `url`. So in a code above I am kind of telling - "order this list by their keys and use `url` as a param value. Url value should be as in url"... That makes no sense. Am I doing it right?

Comment: So url is the unique key of each article?

Comment: yes, its generated by Firebase for each Article

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your database looks like this:

```
articles
  "-KsWM-xif_wPxIvsu5CZ"
     prop1: "..."
     prop2: "..."
  "-KsWNf4AOuuGGsBfeIlg"
     prop1: "..."
     prop2: "..."
```

this should work:

```
findArticlesByUrl(url: string) {
   return this.afDb.object('articles/' + url).do(console.log);
}
```